# Find with winget.exe all packages and save the package ID and package Name with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, winget

I would like to use [winget](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli) to search for **all** packages and store them in a text file or a variable. Later on I would like to sort them in a list with "Name" and "ID". Unfortunately it seems like you cannot search just for winget package Names and IDs directly using [winget.exe](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli)

What I have tried so far:

```
Clear-Host

if (Test-Path -path "$env:temp\download_winget"){
    write-host "Folder exists. Continuing..."
}
else{
    write-Host "There is no folder called winget_download!`nCreating..."
    mkdir "$env:temp\download_winget"
    
}

$get_winget_packages = winget search . --accept-source-agreements | Out-File "$env:temp\download_winget\winget_packages.txt" -Encoding utf8
```

(Yes I know, you can also use `winget search """"`)

My Output: (a sample) (using `get-content "$env:temp\download_winget\winget_packages.txt"`)

```
Name                                      ID                                  Version            Ãœbereinstimmung Quelle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
...
...
Windows Package Manager Manifest Creator  Microsoft.WingetCreate              1.1.2.0                            winget
Remote Desktop Services Infrastructure Aâ€¦ Microsoft.WindowsVirtualDesktopAgeâ€¦ 1.0.5739.9800                      winget
Windows Terminal Preview                  Microsoft.WindowsTerminal.Preview   1.16.3463.0                        winget
Windows Admin Center                      Microsoft.WindowsAdminCenter        1.3.53858.0                        winget
Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit     Microsoft.WindowsADK                10.1.22621.1                       winget
...
...
...
```

As you can see, I displayed with `gc "$env:temp\download_winget\winget_packages.txt"` the content of the earlier created file. Unfortunately some of the lines are not displayed correctly. For example:

```
Remote Desktop Services Infrastructure Aâ€¦ Microsoft.WindowsVirtualDesktopAgeâ€¦ 1.0.5739.9800                      winget
```

I did not find any solution to get all winget packages full Name or full ID using `winget search .`
Even running this directly in PowerShell or CMD, it will display some package Names and ID not fully. Changing the Encoding to utf32, ascii, utf7 or something else wont change anything too. 
Is there a workaround to show the correct/full names of all winget packages Name and ID?

I even tried it with a new powershell process with windowstyle maximized:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList ("winget search ." , "| Out-File '$env:temp\download_winget\winget_packages_lol.txt' -Encoding utf8") -WindowStyle Maximized
```

My Output (a sample):

```
Name                                      ID                                  Version            Ãœbereinstimmung Quelle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BitRecover Windows Live Mail Converter Wizard         BitRecover.WindowsLiveMailConverÔÇª 7.5          winget
```

or

```
Name                                      ID                                  Version            Ãœbereinstimmung Quelle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECLiPSe Constraint Logic Programming System Version ÔÇª Coninfer.ECLiPSeCLP.7.0           7.0 #63      winget
```

My next steps would look like this:

```
$file = gc "$env:temp\download_winget\winget_packages_lol.txt"
$file | sort | Get-Unique | Set-Content "$env:temp\download_winget\winget_packages_lol.txt"
```

I would also work here with substrings, but as mentioned earlier this can't work if I can't get the full winget packages Name and ID.
What can I do here?

Comment: How about the powershell winget module?  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WinGet

Comment: @js2010 I looked it up, but as you can See on https://github.com/ethanbergstrom/winget/issues/12 or https://github.com/ethanbergstrom/winget/issues/2 there is no possibility to do this... maybe there is no solution cause winget-cli just drops .....**$! Output

Comment: Seems like this is a know issue: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/2603

Comment: Winget output is a challenge to parse.  I'm hoping an official powershell version is on the way.

Comment: Maybe set-content would work better than out-file.

Comment: How about Cobalt, A PowerShell Crescendo wrapper for WinGet https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=crescendobuilt

Answer (score 0):

WinGet [releases](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases) have started including a Microsoft.WinGet.Client powershell module in the "Assets" section.